# Nest.js DTO transform and expose multiple fields from same object

Tags: nestjs, class-transformer

I have a nested object that I am calling `plainToInstance` in my controller on which looks like this:

```
{
    "car": {
        "drivetrain": "4WD",
        "engineSize": "2.0L",
        "fuelType": "Gasoline"
    },
    "trailer": {
        ...
    }
}
```

I only want to return the drivetrain and engineSize fields from my controller.

The DTO I'm using to try to do this looks like:

```
@Expose({name: 'car'})
@Transform(({value}) => value.drivetrain)
drivetrain: string;

@Expose({name: 'car'})
@Transform(({value}) => value.engineSize)
engineSize: string;
```

But it is not working and returns

```
"car": "4WD"
```

Comment: It seems that you have to use `@Expose()` with your naming correctly. Like `@Expose({ name: ''drivetrain })` and `@Transform(({ value }) => value.car.drivetrain)`.

And use the same with `engineSize`. But i might be wrong because i have never used those decorators